# How to unlock/erase BIOS password locked hard disks without the original computers?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, formatting

There are a bunch of 2.5" mechanical hard disks (80GB) left from old laptops (over 10 years). I recorded their BIOS hard disk passwords in a spreadsheet. All the laptops that they came from are gone.

When I connect these hard disks into another computer and boot, they prompt for hard disk passwords at the very beginning stage (most likely before BIOS). However, I tried most of the possible and recorded passwords and they do not unlock the hard disks.

#### Is it possible that the BIOS locked hard disks require the original computers to unlock them?

If there is no way to unlock them, I will sacrifice the data and would like to format and reuse those storages.

If connected via SATA, those drives are not visible in Windows `Computer Management` > `Disk Management`. They are not visible in `DiskPart` > `list disk` neither.

If connected via USB (using a connector), the disk is shown in `Disk Management` at state "Not Initialized". However "Initialize Disk" gives the `The media is write protected` error.

If connected via USB, it is also visible in `DiskPart`. But it is still write protected.

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          298 GB      0 B
* Disk 1    Online           74 GB    74 GB

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart has encountered an error: The media is write protected.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

In Linux:

- They appears in `lsblk` as `sda` with no partitions.
- `fdisk /dev/sda` gives the `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error` message.
- `parted /dev/sda` results in `Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error (Retry/Ignore?)`. I can choose ignore. Then `mklabel gpt` gives the same error again.

It is quite similar to [the issue from another thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604453). But my hard disks are from Fujitsu and Hitachi, not WD. The WD Drive Utilities cannot detect my disks.

Comment: Someone ih hddguru forums may be able to help you.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thanks for this tips. I just see some software from their website. Definitely I will try them out.

Comment: No, I mean the forums, https://forum.hddguru.com/, if it can be fixed, they'll know.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that the BIOS locked hard disks require the original
> computers to unlock them?

If you (or someone) set a hard drive password with the laptop when it was alive and running, then you need to change / remove the hard drive password in that laptop with that laptop BIOS.

Can you remove / unlock the hard drive 10 years later?  No. That will not work.

Even during the most recent decade, hard drive passwords cannot be defeated (95% true).

So you need the password that you (or someone) created some years back, and the laptop and BIOS where it was created.

**Additional Note:**

I have worked on 2 (and more) similar laptops before with HD locks, and the drive had to be unlocked (password removed) in the original machine even though the machines were the same laptop models.

HD security is meant to be just that - secure

Comment: Oh really? It seems so weird to me. May I confirm, even if my password is correct, but I do not have the original laptop, I cannot unlock or even cannot erase the hard disk?

Comment: There is not much you can do.  I have worked on 2 similar laptops before with HD locks, and the drive had to be unlocked in the original machine even though the two were the same laptop models. HD security is meant to be just that - secure.

Comment: @John Is this because the hard drive password is somehow tied into hardware IDs? Meaning some machine specific serial number is used as part of a hashing scheme on the password used for the hard drive? Seems like that would be the case but just asking for clarification.

Comment: @John Thanks for sharing your experience. It is kind of sad that those HDD can only turn into garbage. I understand HDD security works this way. But if it forces me to format/erase it, data is protected and HDD can be reused.

Comment: @John May be I need to look for Fujitsu and Hitachi software, which are equivalent to the WD one.

Comment: The great majority of laptops (no black no white) will not allow a HD password to be be changed or removed without the laptop.